# how to mount LCD/TFT screen on raspberry pi

Tags: kernel, touchscreen, dsi

### Possible Duplicate


Raspberry pi has an on-board `DSI` connector, If I buy an **LCD** or **TFT** or **touch screen** which has the `DSI` connector, could I mount it on the `RPI`? Does it require any additional firmware or library for display or will the `kernel` handle that?

I just compiled custom `kernel` with minimal root file system with `busybox` so no gui is available  right now. I have connected the `RPI` with TV and it's working fine I need these feature with **LCD** or **Touch Screen**, I was not able to find any documentation for `RPI` [screens](http://elinux.org/RPi_Screens).

Is those screens works for `RPI` [US $14.88](http://www.aliexpress.com/product-fm/377987722-Replacement-LCD-Glass-Screen-Display-for-iPhone-3GS-wholesalers.html) & [US $14.28](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Repair-LCD-Glass-Screen-Display-Iphone-4G-4th-4-GEN-/110821471601) ?

Could anyone resolve the matter?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the GPU driver code? It might offer some perspective on using the DSI interface. If I am not wrong, the GPU drivers were made open source recently. This [question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/512/dsi-video-connector) offers some perspective.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? If so, could you mark an answer as such or create a self-answer and mark it. We are trying to get the site Q:A up and this question looks to be resolved in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the AdaFruit web site! They've got hardware and tutorials for lots of rPi add-ons.
Take a look at [PiTFT - 2.8" Touchscreen Display for RaspberryPi](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi)